# Restrict linux process write permission to one folder

Tags: linux, chroot, access-control, jails, read-write

I want a process (and all its potential children) to be able to read the filesystem according to my user profile but I want to restrict that process's write permission to only a set of pre-selected folders (potentially only one).

`chroot` seems to act too broadly. Restricting the process to a particular part of the filesystem which makes curbersome the need to mount `/bin` folders and the like. My process should be able read the content of the filesystem as any normal process I launch.

I could use a docker container and mount a volume but that seems overkill: need to install docker, create an image, launch the container in it, etc...

Is there a way to do something like?:

```
restricted-exec --read-all --write-to /a/particular/path --write-to /another/particular/path my-executable -- --option-to-the-executable
```

Some sort of [`unveil`](https://man.openbsd.org/unveil.2) but controlled by the calling process and only for write access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firejail` does the job:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/test && firejail --read-only=/tmp --read-only=~/ --read-write=~/test/ touch ~/test/OK ~/KO /tmp/KO
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use `systemd`.  It has a number of settings that control file system access like `ReadOnlyPaths` and `ReadWritePaths`.

Here is a quick example of running a command using `systemd-run` that only has write access to `/var/lib`.  In the example, `touch` is used to create files in a number of directories, but only the writable path succeeds.

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemd-run --wait -p ProtectSystem=strict -p ProtectHome=read-only -p ReadWritePaths=/var/lib bash -c
'touch /etc/myfile /var/lib/myfile /var/cache/myfile /root/myfile /home/ubuntu/myfile'
Running as unit: run-u1008.service
Finished with result: exit-code
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=1
Service runtime: 44ms
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l {/etc/,/var/lib/,/var/cache/,/root/,/home/ubuntu/}myfile
ls: cannot access '/etc/myfile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/cache/myfile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/root/myfile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/myfile': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 23:17 /var/lib/myfile
```

**edit**

You can run the command as a user with the option `-p User`.  Unfortunately, you need root access to use my suggestion because you can **not** use the file system protections with `--user` (based on [Why doesn't `systemd-run --user` enforce restrictions such as `ProtectSystem`?](https://serverfault.com/questions/880523/why-doesnt-systemd-run-user-enforce-restrictions-such-as-protectsystem)).

Here is another quick example.  This time the command is run as the `ubuntu` user.

```
root@ubuntu:~# install -o ubuntu -g ubuntu -d /tmp/{test,test2}
root@ubuntu:~# systemd-run --wait -p User=ubuntu -p ProtectSystem=strict -p ProtectHome=read-only -p ReadWritePaths=/tmp/test bash -c 'touch /tmp/test/myfile /tmp/test2/myfile /home/ubuntu/myfile'
Running as unit: run-u1043.service
Finished with result: exit-code
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=1
Service runtime: 55ms
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /tmp/{test,test2}/myfile /home/ubuntu/myfile
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test2/myfile': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/myfile': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Mar  5 17:37 /tmp/test/myfile
```

If you are interested in `/tmp` protection then you could also consider the `PrivateTmp` feature of systemd.  This is just one of many more systemd settings that can be used to sandbox processes.

Comment: Thanks you. Running as root is not an option but apparently you can run it with `--user`. The command protect the home folder but not the rest of the system. For example: `mkdir -p /tmp/test /tmp/test2 && systemd-run --user --wait -p ProtectSystem=strict -p ProtectHome=read-only -p ReadWritePaths=/tmp/test bash -c 'touch /tmp/test/OK /tmp/test2/KO`. `/tmp/test2/KO` is created.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I appended an edit to address your comment.  The `systemd-run` command does need to be run as root, but the sandboxed process does not.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Lowther, looking at the question from the answer you are referencing, it seems that `firejail` does the job: `mkdir -p test && firejail --read-only=/tmp --read-only=~/ --read-write=~/test/ touch ~/test/OK ~/KO /tmp/KO`. Don't need any root access.